# Python/PIL os.listdir permission error

Tags: python, django, linux, centos

I had to install a Django 1.4 project on a CentOS system (running python 2.4) so I've build python 2.7 at /opt/python2.7/, so far so good.

I have uploaded the project, changed permissions (chown -r apache:apache ./) and everything seems to work fine, EXCEPT **listing** uploads. The upload itself goes well, the (sub)folders and file are created correctly (example /media/cache/thumbnail.jpg)

However when trying to list files (viewing the admin/change_form.html standard django template) I get this error:

```
(site-packages/PIL/Image.py in init)

for file in os.listdir(directory): 
    ...

13, permission denied
```

Is this caused because I installed python as root and the project/wsgi is ran by the apache user? Is there a clean way to fix this? changing permissions to the /media/ folder seems to have no affect so I assume this is caused by the site-packages permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic permissions problem. To *list directory contents* the user needs *execute* permission on the parent directory.

Fix your permissions accordingly and you shouldn't have problems.

Note that changing the owner with `chown` doesn't modify the permissions, just the owner and group.  The permissions remain whatever the defaults are for your system, which are controlled by [`umask`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

Comment: Yes you're right I forgot the obvious, that is to check the upmost project directory which wasn't configured correctly, thanks